# Loading multiple time series simultaneously using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, time-series

Suppose I have this exact dataset:

| date | widget ID | widget price | widget expiry date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | A | 1 | 2020-03-01 |
| 2020-01-01 | B | 2 | 2020-04-01 |
| 2020-01-01 | C | 3 | 2020-05-01 |
| 2020-01-01 | D | 4 | 2020-06-01 |
| 2020-01-02 | A | 1.1 | 2020-03-01 |
| 2020-01-02 | B | 2.05 | 2020-04-01 |
| 2020-01-02 | C | 3.7 | 2020-05-01 |
| 2020-01-02 | D | 3.8 | 2020-06-01 |
| 2020-01-03 | A | 1.15 | 2020-03-01 |
| 2020-01-03 | B | 2.09 | 2020-04-01 |
| 2020-01-03 | C | 3.54 | 2020-05-01 |
| 2020-01-03 | D | 4.2 | 2020-06-01 |
| 2020-01-04 | A | 1.19 | 2020-03-01 |
| 2020-01-04 | B | 2.14 | 2020-04-01 |
| 2020-01-04 | C | 3.73 | 2020-05-01 |
| 2020-01-04 | D | 4.30 | 2020-06-01 |

Say I wanted to simultaneously retrieve the full time series of the two following widgets using a single SQL query:

- the widget which on date 2020-01-01 had price as close as possible to 1 and expiry date as close as possible to 2020-03-10.
- the widget which on date 2020-01-03 had price as close as possible to 3.5 and expiry date as close as possible to 2020-05-15.

In other words, this exact table:

| date | widget ID | widget price | widget expiry date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | A | 1 | 2020-03-01 |
| 2020-01-01 | C | 3 | 2020-05-01 |
| 2020-01-02 | A | 1.1 | 2020-03-01 |
| 2020-01-02 | C | 3.7 | 2020-05-01 |
| 2020-01-03 | A | 1.15 | 2020-03-01 |
| 2020-01-03 | C | 3.54 | 2020-05-01 |
| 2020-01-04 | A | 1.19 | 2020-03-01 |
| 2020-01-04 | C | 3.73 | 2020-05-01 |

How would you recommend going about it?

Generalising this example, suppose you had a list of tuples like below, where price_i is a target price and expiry_date_i is a target expiry date.

(date_1, price_1, expiry_date_1), (date_2, price_2, expiry_date_2),
(date_3, price_3, expiry_date_3),...

How would you load all of the corresponding widgets' time series in one go?

For the time being I am retrieving these widgets' IDs separately using a SQL query like this one (in this example date='2020-01-01', price=1, expiry date='2020-03-10'). Then collecting all of these retrieved IDs I load the full widget time series.

```
WITH sample AS 
(SELECT *, ABS(DATEDIFF(day,widget_expiry_date, '2020-03-10')) AS date_diff, ABS(widget_price - 1) As price_diff 
FROM data WHERE date='2020-01-01'
ORDER BY date_diff ASC, price_diff ASC)
SELECT TOP 1 widget_ID FROM sample
```

As you can imagine this is extremely inefficient. I wonder if there is a smarter way about it?

Thank you for your time and apologies in advance for the noobish question.

Comment: As before, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And note that TOP is not a MySQL construct

Comment: Strawberry you have to bear with me. This is an extremely basic and reproducible example, i have wittled the problem down to its bone

Comment: its not clear , for example why date='2020-01-01' , the expiry date should be close to expiry date='2020-03-10' or  2020-05-15 , is expirydate always  thhese date fro all "date" s?

Comment: here (date, price, expiry_date) = (2020-01-01, 1, 2020-03-10). Given this input i am trying to load the time series of the widget which on date 2020-01-01 had price as close as possible to 1 and expiry date as close as possible to 2020-03-10. This tuple would be a user input so i would prefer not to search for exact matches (since these might not exist)

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving all the series in a single query

```
with params (date_, price_, expiry_date_) AS (
   select date '2020-01-01', 1,   date '2020-03-10' union all
   select date '2020-01-03', 3.5, date '2020-05-15' 
)
select data.*
from params p
join data on data.widgetID = (
   SELECT widgetID
   FROM data d
   WHERE d.date = p.date_
   ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(d.widget_expiry_date, p.expiry_date_))  ASC, ABS(d.widget_price - p.price_) ASC
   LIMIT 1);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=020519b4ccc11b0194592bf9504e22f0)

Answer (score 0):

you also can use window functions:

```
SELECT indate , widgetID ,  price , expirydate FROM (
SELECT * 
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY indate ORDER BY ABS(price - 1), ABS(DATEDIFF(expirydate, '2020-03-10')) ) rn1 
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY indate ORDER BY ABS(price - 3.5), ABS(DATEDIFF(expirydate, '2020-05-15')) ) rn2
FROM  widgets
) t
WHERE rn1 =1 OR rn2 = 1
ORDER BY indate , widgetID
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9de27b67bbdad28067742c6c5a685f5e)*

Comment: Thanks eshirvana, sorry what is "indate" here?

Comment: @jraffaud just renamed "date" column , since date is a reserved word

Comment: @Strawberry see 
[MySQL 8.0 Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

Comment: @Strawberry my point is "date" is a reserved word as it's been mentioned in the mysql documentation and it's the case in almost every dbms.

Comment: well, its a keyword , I should have been more clear

Comment: Well, I suppose.